# Does Foxx/ArangoDB Server support Socket.IO?

Tags: socket.io, arangodb, foxx

I was wondering if Foxx/ArangoDB supports Socket.io ? Or would I have to fire a separate Express.js server if I want to use sockets.io ?

Answer (score 4):

closing this QA, found threads below.

https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/issues/602 - Add support for websockets

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/arangodb/F4geU6_KI8M - ArangoDB and Web Sockets